# How gain write access to DCIM directory on removable media in Android?

Tags: android, permissions

My code is follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        writeFile();
    }



    public void writeFile()  {

        File removableRoot = RootsUtil.getRemovableRoots(this)[0];
        File DCIMDirectory = new File(removableRoot, "DCIM");
        File cameraDirectory = new File(DCIMDirectory, "Camera");

        if( cameraDirectory.exists() ) {
            try {
                String filename = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date()) + ".txt";


                //cameraDirectory.mkdirs();
                File file = new File(cameraDirectory, filename);
                FileWriter writer = null;

                writer = new FileWriter(file);
                PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(writer);
                printWriter.println("Hello World");

                printWriter.close();
                writer.close();

                System.out.println("Number of files: " + cameraDirectory.listFiles().length);

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`cameraDirectory` equals to `/storage/9C33-6BBD/DCIM/Camera` before if and it exists. This where my `Camera` application stores it's files.

I am trying to write file into this directory too, but fails with the following exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/9C33-6BBD/DCIM/Camera/20170204_192001.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:42)
    at com.inthemoon.trycamerawrite.MainActivity.writeFile(MainActivity.java:48)
    at com.inthemoon.trycamerawrite.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
    ... 17 more
```

Apparently, I have no permission to write to this directory. How to obtain this permission?

**UPDATE**

I have modified the code in the following way:

```
private static final int RQS_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE, Uri.fromFile(cameraDirectory));
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);

        //writeFile();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        writeFile();
    }
```

and then allowing user to manually select `DCIM/Camera` and this doesn't help.

Comment: other folder works?

Comment: have you given write storage permission in manifest?

Comment: What's your target sdk ? in gradle?

Comment: `cameraDirectory.mkdirs();`. Do not call mkdirs() blindly. First check if the directory exists. And check the return value as it might fail to create the directory in which case it returns false. If so display a toast to the user saying so. And return. Do not continue with your code then as it makes little sense trying to create a file in a directory that does not exist.

Comment: @greenapps sorry I am obliged to continue experimenting because nobody seems to know the answer I need; the more value it will have when I find it :)

Comment: `I would like files go to

/storage/9C33-6BBD/DCIM/Camera`. Well than use that path to write to. What´s the problem exactly? Besides that there normallay is no DCIM directory yet.

Comment: `sorry I am obliged to continue experimenting`. Of course. But that should not hinder you in adapting your code the way i suggested.

Comment: @greenapps system doesn't not allow me to write at that location

Comment: Yes i know. But you were asking something different.

Comment: About how to call mkdirs? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to write directly to the filesystem of removable storage. That will not work, except for select directories that are unique to your app (e.g., ones returned by `getExternalFilesDirs()`).

Using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` does not magically grant you filesystem access. What it *does* do is give you a `Uri` that you can use, in conjunction with `ContentResolver`, `DocumentFile`, and kin, to work with documents and collections based on that `Uri`.

`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` is part of [the storage access framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html), covered in the documentation.

Android 7.0+ also provides [scoped directory access](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/scoped-directory-access.html), which provides a simpler way for the user to grant you access to something like `DCIM/` on removable storage. However, it too gives you a `Uri`, and you would still use `ContentResolver`, `DocumentFile`, and so on to work with content and collections based on that `Uri`.

Comment: I have nothing against an `Uri`. I just want to know, how having an `Uri`, can I write "Hello world" text into referenced file :) Is this possible?

Comment: @Dims: Again, it's not a file. Use `fromTreeUri()` to create a `DocumentFile` for the chosen tree. [Use `createFile()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/provider/DocumentFile.html#createFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to create a `DocumentFile` pointing at the location within that tree that you want to write to. Call `getUri()` on that `DocumentFile` to get the `Uri` to the document. Pass that to `openOutputStream()` on a `ContentResolver`. Then, write to the stream, `flush()` the stream, and `close()` the stream.

Comment: Okay, why then can't I just make uri with `Uri.fromFile(myPoorFile)` and then continue your recipe from words "Pass that to openOurputStream"?

Comment: @Dims: Because you do not have direct write access to the filesystem. The `Uri` you are getting from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` and from `getUri()` will have a `content` scheme. You are telling a `ContentProvider` what to write; it is writing that content to wherever makes sense, based on the `Uri`. In the case of removable storage, the system-supplied provider for removable storage has write access to it, whereas your app does not have write access to arbitrary locations on it.

Comment: Okay, but can I get good Uri ANYWAY without bothering my user?

Comment: @Dims: No, because the user has to give you permission to work with the location, wherever that location is.

Comment: Can we gain this permission once, during program install, as it usually happens for other permissions (most of which are much more sensible that this)?

Comment: For example, permission to spy my geolocation or to record my phonecalls, which are very vital, can be obtained once, but permission to write to my owm private SD card should be refreshed each couch?

Comment: @Dims: Not during install. Also, `dangerous` permissions such as the ones you cite require runtime interaction with the user on Android 6.0+, once your `targetSdkVersion` reaches 23 or higher. With respect to `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, once you get the `Uri`, call [`takePersistableUriPermission()` on a `ContentResolver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#takePersistableUriPermission(android.net.Uri,%20int)) to get durable access to that tree.

Comment: Okay, can I hint user which directory to choose, can I preset his screen, allowing him just to accept?

Comment: @Dims: Not that I am aware of. Moreover, if the user wants to put the photos elsewhere (e.g., external storage, Google Drive), that is the user's decision to make. The point behind the storage access framework is to abstract away the actual "physical" location of content, so apps can work with providers without caring about the details, giving users flexibility to store content where and how they want.